# How to add css for both label and input field in django from form.py

Tags: python, django

I want to create Django form with label and input. i successfully add css class to input field but i don't know how to add css class to its input label

form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import TestForm


class addForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestForm
        fields = ('name', 'address', 'mobile')

        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
       
            'address': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'mobile': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }
```

Model.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class TestForm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

addform.html

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}

{%block main%}


<div class="row clearfix" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="body">
                            <h2 class="card-inside-title">Floating Label Examples</h2>
                            <div class="row clearfix">

                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group form-float">
                                        <div class="form-line">
                                            <form method="post"/>
                                                {% csrf_token%}
                                                {{form.as_p}}
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

{%endblock%}
```

Current Output:-

```
<label for="id_name">Name:</label> 
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" maxlength="50" required id="id_name">
```

Required Output :-

```
<input type="text" class="form-control">
<label class="form-label">Username</label>
```

Did not get class in label, guys please help me how can i get class in label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t have to let Django unpack the form’s fields; you can do it manually if you like. Each field is available as an attribute of the form using `{{ form.name_of_field }}`, and in a Django template, will be rendered appropriately. As you unpack the form with `form.as_p` you can add your css classes like :

```
<p><label class="my-classes" for="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}">Name:</label>
    {{ form.name }}</p>
<p><label class="my-classes" for="{{ form.address.id_for_label }}">Address:</label>
    {{ form.address}}</p>
<p><label class="my-classes" for="{{ form.mobile.id_for_label }}">Mobile:</label>
    {{ form.mobile}}</p>
```

[[docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)